# Create a procedure with Alter Database option

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, encryption, database-backups, tde

I have more than 30 dbs which are encrypted with TDE. Now I have to make a backup of each db without encryption.
Following step are needed: 
- Set encryption off
- Do a full backup of that db
- Set encryption on

(Sry, but I am not so good at coding)

Here an example what I did so far:

```
use [Testt]
ALTER DATABASE [Testt] 
SET ENCRYPTION OFF
Go


BACKUP DATABASE [Testt] 
TO  DISK = N'J:\Backup\Testt_full.bak ' WITH NOFORMAT,COPY_ONLY, NOINIT,  
NAME = N'J:\Testt', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO 

GO
use [Testt]
ALTER DATABASE [Testt] 
SET ENCRYPTION ON
GO
```

Is there any easier way to do this for 30 dbs? I thought about a procedure or a cursor

Comment: check out sp_msforeachdb

Comment: I would first recommend to do the entire thing in a transaction. Second, I think it should probably be easiest to run it from a script platform like powershell.

Comment: @Zohar Peled: do backups enlist in transactions?......

Comment: @MitchWheat I don't know about backups with I think that set encryption do...

Comment: AFAIK they don't......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store in #tmp  your database names

```
DECLARE @dbName nvarchar(MAX) =''
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) = ''

DECLARE Crs CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
SELECT data
FROM #tmp 


OPEN Crs 
FETCH NEXT FROM Crs into @dbName 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN



SET @sql= 'use' + @dbName +
'ALTER DATABASE' + @dbName +
'SET ENCRYPTION OFF'

EXEC(@sql)

DECLARE @dName nvarchar(MAX) = 'J:\\' + @dbName 
DECLARE @dPath nvarchar(MAX) = 'J:\\Backup\\' + @dbName + '_full.bak'

SET @sql='BACKUP DATABASE ' + @dbName +
'TO  DISK = '+ @dPath +' WITH 
NOFORMAT,COPY_ONLY, NOINIT,  
NAME = '+ @dName  +', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10'

EXEC(@sql)

SET @sql= 'use  ' + @dbName +
'ALTER DATABASE  ' + @dbName +
'SET ENCRYPTION ON'

 EXEC(@sql)

FETCH NEXT FROM Crs into @dbName 


END


CLOSE Crs

DEALLOCATE Crs
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help...when i am trying the cursor part, I get following error message:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near '\'.

Msg 132, Level 15, State 1, Line 28
The label 'J' has already been declared. Label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Claudio Biselli for your help:

I adjusted you cursor part:

```
DECLARE @dbName nvarchar(MAX) =''
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @sql2 nvarchar(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @sql3 nvarchar(MAX) = ''

DECLARE Crs CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
SELECT d.name
FROM sys.databases d
INNER JOIN
sys.dm_database_encryption_keys e ON d.database_id = e.database_id
where d.name not like 'tempdb'

OPEN Crs 
FETCH NEXT FROM Crs into @dbName 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN


SET @sql= 'use ' + @dbName +
' ALTER DATABASE ' + @dbName + ' SET ENCRYPTION OFF'
select @sql


SET @sql2='BACKUP DATABASE ' + @dbName +
' TO  DISK = ''J:\Backup\' + @dbName + '_full.bak'' WITH NOFORMAT, COPY_ONLY, NOINIT, NAME = ''J:\'+ @dbName + ''', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10'
select @sql2


SET @sql3= 'use ' + @dbName +
' ALTER DATABASE ' + @dbName + ' SET ENCRYPTION ON'
select @sql3

FETCH NEXT FROM Crs into @dbName 
END
CLOSE Crs
DEALLOCATE Crs
```

And it works:)